# Inspecting firefox with firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, inspect, chromebug

Using [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/) I found an interesting feature. If I pick a color from firefox (bars,tabs or anything else of the browser) and then go to:

> ColorZilla > Inspect Last Element > In
>   Firebug

Then I can see the markup,css,js that firefox uses in the firebug panel just like a website.
[image]

Is there any solution to view this code without use Colorzilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're after [Chromebug](http://blog.getfirebug.com/category/chromebug/).

> Chromebug is the Firebug code adapted
>   for XUL applications. It is the
>   debugger that Firebug developers use
>   to develop Firebug.

So you can debug your debugger, you know?

Instructions: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug

Comment: chromebug unfortunately only works up to firefox 5. your only bet right now is to open the browser in a tab and inspecting it like so. paste this into the address bar and hit enter: `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` (note that some things will be different, e.g. some addon buttons won’t be there and so on)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, Chromebug is no longer working with current Firefox versions. Instead of opening the limited `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` page, you can make the browser chrome accessible to the scratchpad. Open the `about:config` page and set `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true`, as described in the [extension development environment setup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) guide on MDN.

Open the JavaScript scratchpad (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) and select the browser context environment. Now you can type in something like `window` or `document.getElementById('urlbar')` and click the inspect button or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. This will evaluate the expression and open the element inspector, which shows all properties of the element.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a dedicated version of Firebug for that called [Chromebug](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/10/12/chromebug-1-5a4/) (Named after the chrome of Firefox, not Google's chrome)